# Get username of your Gmail account

Tags: php, google-api, gmail

Hello good day all around, I have a little problem when trying botener the name of a user through the library google API for PHP, all you have achieved until now is to take his name but right through your Google Plus and what I want is to take it through your Gmail account, if this is not possible, so I do it with the kind of Google Plus:

```
$userProfile = $googlePlus->people->get('me');
$name = $userProfile->getName();
echo var_dump($name);
```

As could do with Gmail? This is important because not all users have Google+ account 
Greetings and thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for the sender name? As Gmail uses the email as user name, I can't quite get it.

Comment: I wonder how's your flow. If you use Google SSO login, you should be able to obtain the username.